# Msgbox appears even when it shouldn't excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-2007, msgbox

I'm have a problem with the following code:

```
month = Me.monthcbg.Value
year = Me.yrcbg.Value

If Len(Dir("L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year
End If

If Len(Dir("L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month
    MkDir "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month & "\1_LOP"
    MkDir "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month & "\2_Plants_Operations"
    MkDir "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month & "\3_Logistics_Purchasing_IT"
    MkDir "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month & "\4_Development_Changes"
ElseIf Len(Dir("L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month, vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then
    mes = MsgBox("A presentation already exists, would you like to overwrite the existing presentation?", vbYesNo, "Presentation Exists")
        If mes = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf mes = vbYes Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Kill "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\" & year & "\" & month & "\1_LOP\" & month & "\" & year & ".pptx"
            MsgBox "Old Presentation Deleted"
            Set Error = 0
        End If
End If
```

Month and year are dimensioned as strings. The first problem is that the msgbox always appears even if there is no existing directory, the second problem is even if vbyes is selected the code does not create the directory.

Thanks

Comment: Well it does not create it because it does not start over. Although I hate looping like this you can add `GoTo 0` at the end of the vbYes if statement to start the code over.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `month/year` as variables. They are reserved names in vba

Comment: `the second problem is even if vbyes is selected the code does not create the directory.` It doesn't create it because you are not asking it to. I do not see a `MKDIR` statement there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not actually see an issue with the code but I have cleaned it up a bit

```
Dim root_dir As String
Dim sub_dir(3) AS String

month_str = Me.monthcbg.Value
year_str = Me.yrcbg.Value

root_dir = "L:\NAI_Groups\IS Monthly Operations Meeting\"  & year_str
sub_dir(0) = "\1_LOP"
sub_dir(1) = "\2_Plants_Operations"
sub_dir(2) = "\3_Logistics_Purchasing_IT"
sub_dir(3) = "\4_Development_Changes"

If Len(Dir(root_dir, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir root_dir


If Len(Dir( root_dir "\" & month_str, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir root_dir & "\" & month_str
    For i =0  to UBound(sub_dir) -1
         MkDir root_dir & "\" & month_str & "\" & sub_dir(i)
    Next i
Else 
    mes = MsgBox("A presentation already exists, would you like to overwrite the existing presentation?", vbYesNo, "Presentation Exists")
        If mes = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf mes = vbYes Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Kill root_dir & "\" & month_str & "\1_LOP\" & month_str & "\" & year_str & ".pptx"
            MsgBox "Old Presentation Deleted"
            Set Error = 0
            Goto 0
        End If
End If
```